# Gradle zip: how to include and rename one file easily?

Tags: gradle, zip, rename

Create a zip adding file `"hello/world.xml"` under directory `"foo/bar"` as `"hello/universe.xml"`

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
     from ("foo/bar") {
         include "hello/world.xml"
         filesMatching("hello/*") {
             it.path = "hello/universe.xml"
         }
     }
}
```

`filesMatching(...)` will impact performance obviously.
What is a better way? like:

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
     from ("foo/bar") {
         include ("hello/world.xml") {
              rename "hello/universe.xml"
         }         
     }
}
```

But `rename` is not supported with `include`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't get why you are using `filesMatching` at all. You are only including one single file in your child [`CopySpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html). Simply rename it and everything is fine:

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
    from ('foo/bar') {
        include 'hello/world.xml'
        rename { 'hello/universe.xml' }
    }
}
```

If you want to include multiple files (or even copy all), but only want to rename one of them, specify which file(s) to rename with a regular expression as first argument:

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
    from 'foo/bar'
    rename 'hello/world.xml' 'hello/universe.xml'
}
```

Comment: For regular expression, does it need to match the whole file name, or any pattern as used in java string.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)? thanks.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) say: "Files that do not match the source regular expression will be copied with the original name." So I assume that any match would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the last one did not work, try:

```
rename ('a.java', 'b.java')
```